# In how many ways can five items be selected from $20$ good and $4$ defective items?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I have a batch of $4$ defective items (d) and $20$ good items (g). I want to select an ordered set of two items, without replacement. This is simple to figure out, with a sample space $S=\{dg,gd,dd,gg\}= 4$ sets.

So now let's say I want to select an ordered sample set of only $5$ items, again without replacement, using the d & g items still. How do I go about this?

My attempt: I only know simple permutations/combination formulas. So I have $24$ items, $4$ identical, and $20$ identical, and I want to make different ordered sets without replacement. I know how to make a different ordered sets with all $24$, which would be $$\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!} = \frac{24!}{4!20!}$$

But, I do not know how to only have a set of five AND worry about those repeated items. Thank you.

Comment: Please, you should be using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) by now.

Comment: But try using stars and bars.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_principles

Comment: Note that your approach doesn't create an equi-probable sample space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 5 places to fill. $$\_ \; \_ \; \_ \; \_ \; \_$$
You will have two cases.

Case 1: You run out of defective elements. Here, you have used all 4 defective elements. So, you can place 4 d's in any 4 of 5 places in $\binom{5}{4}$. In the remaining place, you have to put a g.

Case 2: You don't run out of defective elements. So you can have maximum 3 d's. The remaining places must be filled by g's. So you have $\binom{5}{3}+\binom{5}{2}+\binom{5}{1}+\binom{5}{0}$

Add all to get the final result.

**Edit**: A simpler way would be to fill in the g's. You cannot not have g in any set. So the total number of sets will be $\binom{5}{1}+\binom{5}{2}+\binom{5}{3}+\binom{5}{4}+\binom{5}{5}$